# Making rectangular image an irregular shape on a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

After searching the web for just over an hour, I have not found any luck.

I am wondering if it is possible, if so how do I create a transparent image on a js canvas not to be considered as a rectangle, rather only the visible area of it.

For example if you click in a transparent spot on the png the script does not considered that part of the object.

Thank you :)

Comment: could you start from a good book :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get info about every pixel on the canvas using `context.getImageData`

A Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/tMmzc/

This code will get an array containing info about every pixel on the canvas:

```
var data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;
```

The `data` array is organized with 4 sequential element representing the red,green,blue & alpha(opacity) information about one pixel.

```
The data array's elements #0-3 have the top-left pixel's r,g,b,a info.

The data array's elements #4-7 have the next rightward pixel's r,g,b,a info.

...and so on...
```

Therefore, given the mouse position on the canvas you can fetch that pixel's alpha info.  If the alpha value is zero then that pixel is transparent.

This code will read the alpha value under the mouse and determine if it's transparent:

```
var isTransparent = data[(mouseY*canvas.width+mouseX)*4+3]>0;
```